# Binding an NSPopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nspopupbutton

OK, so here's my situation :

- I've got an `NSDictionary`, let's call it : `myItem`.
- `myItem.valueNames` contains the values that I want to show up in the popup
- `myItem.values` contains the values the popup must return (e.g. for valueName[0] -> value[0], and so on)
- `myItem.value` contains the current value

How am I suppose to bind that? Even though I've studied the official reference, it still looks a bit obscure...

I'm currently binding :

- `myItem.valueNames` to `Content`
- `myItem.values` to `Content Objects`
- `myItem.value` to `Selected Value`

and... all I've managed is that it shows the `valueNames`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is a little strange to me. I wouldn't use an NSDictionary, I'd use a custom subclass with KVC/KVO compliant properties for each of these. Also, if the name of each value is a property of the value object itself, there's no need for a separate `valueNames` property. So, with that change, I'd do this:

- Bind `Content` to `modelObject` with a key path of `values`
- Bind `Content Values` to `modelObject` with a key path of `values.name`
- Bind `Selected Object` to `modelObject` (or `yourControllerObject` if that makes more sense) with a key path of `value` (I'd name it `selectedValue`)